# Permutation of a multiset with restrictions on two characters.

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, permutations, combinations, multisets

Consider the following: apples?and?oranges.

I have to find the number of arrangements with the restriction that the two ? can't be together and they can't be located at the ends like ?applesandoranges?. In other words, there must 3 words(words don't have to mean anything) with at least 1 letter.

My solution:
Let T be the number of permutations without any restrictions. Let S be the number of arrangements where the two ? are together and let R be the number of arrangements with the two ? at the ends.

Since we are finding the arrangements of the multiset $X = \{3*a, 2*p, 2*n, 2*e, 1*l, 2*s, 1*d, 1*o, 1*r, 1*g, 2*?\}$ and $|X| = 18$ then

T = $\frac{18!}{3!2!2!2!2!2!}$

S = $\frac{17!}{3!2!2!2!2!}$ (The divisor has one less 2 because the two ? are being considered as one character so their permutation is not being considered )

R =  $\frac{16!}{3!2!2!2!2!}$ (The two ? are not being considered at all here)

Number of arrangements = T -(R+S)

Did I overlook something? I'd appreciate some feedback.

EDIT:
I will add the restriction that each word must be distinct.

Thank you.

Comment: What about cases where you have a ? at one end like in the example case **??applesandoranges** or  the case **?applesand?oranges**. Don't you want to subtract those too? Be careful of you do because they overlap with some of your previous ones.

Comment: The first case you mentioned is covered by S because S counts the arrangements where you have ??. Or am i missing something there too? Ahh I did not think about the second case you pointed ou. I will redo this.

Comment: There is a much easier way: Ignore the ?s to begin with and just count the ways of arranging the 16 letters. Then, for each arrangement,  *choose* 2 of the 15 gaps between letters to place the ?s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to do this is to arrange the $16$ letters in $16!/(3!2!^4)$ ways then, for each, choose $2$ of the $15$ gaps between letters to place the ?s in $\binom{15}{2}$ ways.

$$\frac{16!}{3!2!^4}\binom{15}{2}\tag{Answer $1$}$$

Alternatively we can push through with your method and create $3$ overlapping sets of arrangements $L$ (the set where a ? is on the left), $R$ (the set where a ? is on the right) and $T$ (the set where ?? are together).

It should be clear that

$$|L|=|R|=|T|=\frac{17!}{3!2^4}$$

and that their intersections have

$$|L\cap R|=|L\cap T|=|R\cap T|=\frac{16!}{3!2!^4}$$

and

$$|L\cap R\cap T|=0$$

then the number of "bad" arrangements is

$$|L|+|R|+|T|-|L\cap R|-|L\cap T|-|R\cap T|+|L\cap R\cap T|= 3\left(\frac{17!}{3!2^4}-\frac{16!}{3!2!^4}\right)$$

which means the number of "good" arrangements is

$$\frac{18!}{3!2!^5}-3\left(\frac{17!}{3!2^4}-\frac{16!}{3!2!^4}\right)\tag{Answer $2$}$$

check that these answers match.

Comment: and what if each word had to be distinct?

Comment: @rachelhoward, that's a good question. I think I would have to use inclusion-exclusion and count the cases where words *are* repeated then subtract them from the total. Notice that you can only have 2 repeated words, and they must come from the set of double and triple letters.

Comment: Yes but there would be a lot of cases to consider. Like repeated words with 1 and 2 letters of the repeated 6 letters.... each would change the value of the divisor. It could be done but sounds tedious....hmmm

Comment: Actually, I don't think it's all that bad (for this example anyway). There are 9 mutually exclusive cases to consider so we don't even need to use inclusion-exclusion as I originally thought. I calculate a total of $127\,863\,360$ arrangements with repeat words.